# Connect two sets of sfc points with arrows

Tags: spatial, r-sf, r-sp

I have a dataframe two columns of which are lists of sfc points.

```
 > head(moves)
   hiring                      start                        end
 1      1 POINT (-2.030474 51.36306) POINT (-2.250102 51.41609)
 2      2 POINT (-2.319776 51.46162) POINT (-2.491189 51.41029)
 3      4 POINT (-2.025846 51.47712) POINT (-2.063781 51.49158)
 4      6 POINT (-2.426711 51.38076) POINT (-2.132722 51.46999)
 5      7  POINT (-2.116654 51.4887) POINT (-2.204403 51.51874)
 6      8  POINT (-2.122917 51.5861) POINT (-2.134635 51.51806)
```

I need to draw lines (ideally, pointed) from one point to another, row by row. My problem seems to be that my file(moves) is not an sf object. Do I need to make it one, or take the data from it into some other format?

```
 > dput(head(moves))
 structure(list(hiring = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L), start = list(
     structure(c(-2.03047447566941, 51.3630641761757), class = c("XY", 
     "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-2.31977575385362, 51.4616210429381
     ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-2.02584648038463, 
     51.4771163047678), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
 structure(c(-2.42671091326068, 
     51.3807643595824), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
 structure(c(-2.1166538974769, 
     51.4887039877758), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
 structure(c(-2.12291705783767, 
     51.5860957106472), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), end = list(
     structure(c(-2.25010169528537, 51.4160891285008), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-2.49118920138511, 51.4102939905029
     ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-2.06378098244424, 
     51.491583244303), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
 structure(c(-2.13272163343155, 
     51.469987047928), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
 structure(c(-2.20440279315621, 
     51.5187438721622), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
 structure(c(-2.1346350057738, 
     51.5180564842074), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")))), row.names = c(NA, 
 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please make the data available, so people can easily run code and help you? You can simply run `dput(head(moves))` and then others can copy/paste the output in their R session and get the data. Also please specify which kind of plot you are looking for. Is it on top of a map or simply a white back ground with arrows pointing between pairs of points?

Comment: I've added the data. Eventually, I'll add the CRS and put it on a map, but right now my issue is to find a way to draw what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple arrows with base graphics on a empty background (no map).

EDIT: With the data now given in the original post I realize that `moves$start` and `moves$end` aren't `sfc` objects but simply lists of `sfg` objects. They can be turned into `sfc` objects with `sf::st_as_sfc` and then the coordinates can be extracted. Full code is:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
moves <- structure(
  list(hiring = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L), 
       start = list(
         structure(c(-2.03047447566941, 51.3630641761757),
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
         structure(c(-2.31977575385362, 51.4616210429381), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
         structure(c(-2.02584648038463, 51.4771163047678), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
         structure(c(-2.42671091326068, 51.3807643595824), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
         structure(c(-2.1166538974769, 51.4887039877758), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
         structure(c(-2.12291705783767, 51.5860957106472), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))),
       end = list(
         structure(c(-2.25010169528537, 51.4160891285008), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
         structure(c(-2.49118920138511, 51.4102939905029), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
         structure(c(-2.06378098244424, 51.491583244303), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
         structure(c(-2.13272163343155, 51.469987047928), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
         structure(c(-2.20440279315621, 51.5187438721622), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
         structure(c(-2.1346350057738, 51.5180564842074), 
                   class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")))), 
       w.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

co_s <- st_coordinates(st_as_sfc(moves$start))
co_e <- st_coordinates(st_as_sfc(moves$end))
s_lon <- co_s[,"X"]
s_lat <- co_s[,"Y"]
e_lon <- co_e[,"X"]
e_lat <- co_e[,"Y"]
plot(c(s_lon, e_lon), c(s_lat, e_lat), col = rep(c("red", "blue"), each = 6),
     pch = 20, cex = 2, xlab = "lon", ylab = "lat")
arrows(s_lon, s_lat, e_lon, e_lat)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is exactly the second part, how to either get the coordinates from of the points defined as sfc objects, or plot the lines based on the pairs of sfc points. st_coordinates does not help.

Comment: Hi Ege, this is great, thank you so much! The only remaining problem is that this does not work with my dataset; the response I receive is "Error in UseMethod("st_as_sfc") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_as_sfc' applied to an object of class "c('sfc_POINT', 'sfc')". Apparently, moves are a dataframe, but this function recognises it as something else. I wonder why?

Comment: In your example `data.frame` the columns are simple lists of class `sfg`. In that case you have to turn them into `sfc` objects with the command `st_as_sfg()`. If your real `data.frame` already has columns of class `sfc` you should omit this part. For example: `co_s <- st_coordinate(moves$start)`. You can check the class of each column with `lapply(moves, class)`. If this solves the problem please accept this answer so other people can see the problem is solved.

Comment: I'm glad it worked @Mikhail. Please consider accepting the answer by pressing the check mark so others can see the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Great question.  Sorry, no arrows. The result has only straight lines.  To get this question to an answer, I needed to convert the "moves" data into two matrix objects: one matrix for the starting points, and the second matrix for the ending points.

```
s_lon <- c(-2.030474, -2.319776, -2.025846, -2.426711, -2.116654, -2.122917)
s_lat <- c(51.36306, 51.46162, 51.47712, 51.38076, 51.4887, 51.5861)
e_lon <- c(-2.250102, -2.491189, -2.063781, -2.132722, -2.204403, -2.134635)
e_lat <- c(51.41609, 51.41029, 51.49158, 51.46999, 51.51874, 51.51806)

# Create matrixes from data

m_s <- matrix(data = c(s_lon, s_lat), nrow = 6, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)
m_e <- matrix(data = c(e_lon, e_lat), nrow = 6, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)
```

Then used a loop to convert the data from each matrix into simple feature geometric points and combined each pair (start point with end point) into a list.

And then plotted each pair of start/end points, and the string that connects them.

```
n <- c(1:6)

myplotfct <- function(i, s1, e1, pt_s1.sfg, pt_e1.sfg, mylist) {
if(i == 1) {
    plot(mylist, axes = TRUE, xlim = c(-2.5, -1.8), ylim = c(51.3, 51.65), pch = 19, cex = 3, col = "red", )
    ln1 <- st_nearest_points(pt_s1.sfg, pt_e1.sfg) 
    plot(ln1, add = TRUE) 
 } else {    
    plot(mylist, add = TRUE, pch = 19, cex = 3, col = "blue")
    ln1 <- st_nearest_points(pt_s1.sfg, pt_e1.sfg) 
    plot(ln1, add = TRUE)
    
    }
 }

my_s <- function(n, .) {   # Start Pt Function
    m_s[n,]    
}


my_e <- function(n, .) {     # End Pt Function
    m_e[n,]
}

for(i in 1:6) {
    s1 <- my_s(i, m_s[x,])     #  Fct call
    e1 <- my_e(i, m_e[x,])
    
    pt_s1.sfg <- st_point(x = c(s1), dim = "XY")  # convert s1 to geometric 
    pt_e1.sfg <- st_point(x = c(e1), dim = "XY")   # convert e1 to geometric
    mylist <- c(pt_s1.sfg, pt_e1.sfg)              # create a list of the two geometric points (start - end)
    myplotfct(i, s1, e1, pt_s1.sfg, pt_e1.sfg, mylist)
   
}
```

The output could be improved by changing the color for each pair if so desired.  The output can be viewed from this [link:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5I8I.png)

Comment: Just a quick tip: If you use the package `reprex` to run your examples you can get code to copy/paste directly as your answer with embedded graphics and everything. Also: I don't understand why you have `.` in the definition of `my_s` and `my_e` since it doesn't seem to be used for anything.